# Is there a way to make a "clickable" button, that is actually a text field?

Tags: java, swing, jtextfield, mouselistener, sudoku

I am making a Sudoku App using Java & Swing, and I was wondering if there was a way to edit one "box" in the 2d array using a MouseEvent and getX(), getY(). So for example, if the board is 500x500 pixels, the pixels from first 99 pixels in each direction would make the first box of a sudoku game...

This is what I have tried:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 9; j++) {
            fieldArray[i][j] = new JLabel(a[i][j] + " ");
        }
    }

    setLayout(new GridLayout(9, 9));

    for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 9; j++) {
            add(fieldArray[i][j]);
        }
    }`public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    
    addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent r) {
             x = r.getX();
             y = r.getY();
             x = x/9;
             y = y/9; 
        }
    });
    
    String s = "";
    if(e.getActionCommand().equals("1")) {
        s += "1";
    }
    if(e.getActionCommand().equals("2")) {
        s += "2";
    }
    if(e.getActionCommand().equals("3")) {
        s += "3";
    }
    if(e.getActionCommand().equals("4")) {
        s += "4";
    }
    if(e.getActionCommand().equals("5")) {
        s += "5";
    }
    if(e.getActionCommand().equals("6")) {
        s += "6";
    }
    if(e.getActionCommand().equals("7")) {
        s += "7";
    }
    if(e.getActionCommand().equals("8")) {
        s += "8";
    }
    if(e.getActionCommand().equals("9")) {
        s += "9";
    }
    if(e.getActionCommand().equals("0")) {
        s += "0";
    }
}`
```

Comment: Short answer, yes there is a way. Just override the selection/click events of each of your JTextFields to perform the appropriate action. The action of one event/click should not influence other components unless you are incorrectly referencing them inside the event method.

Comment: @AndrewThompson I just added more information, hopefully it makes more sense now

Answer (score 0):

Why dont just extends the JTextField class ?

You can do something like that :

```
public class SudokuTextField extends JTextField {

    private int x;
    private int y;

    public SudokuTextField (int x, int y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }
}
```

With this, you can access to the extra info you need